# How to call a method declared in another class

Tags: ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to call a method of another Class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235742/how-to-call-a-method-of-another-class)

i have 2 classes. in the first i have declared a method which has to remove an object from an array in the same class. in the second class i have to call this method from the first class. How can i do it?

Comment: When you entered your title SO replied with about 50 "likely matches" to the title. Of those, at least 10 would have answered your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `MySecondClass.m`

```
MyFirstClass *myFirstObject=[[MyFirstClass alloc]init];

[myFirstObject nameOfMethod];
```

nameOfMethod must be declared in `MyFirstClass.h`

Answer (score 0):

Your first class must have this method declared in its .h file for it to be public so others can call it. It could be something like this:

```
-(void)removeObject:(id)object;
```

Now the instance of the second class can call this by using:

```
[myFirstObject removeObject:someObject];
```

It is of course important that the instance of the first class (in this case `myFirstObject`) exists and is know to the instance of the second class or else his call would go nowhere...

Comment: my first object means the name of the first-class?

Comment: No, `myFirstObject` would be an `instance` of your first `class`. Your class may be called Class1 or whatever, and you create an instance of it and then an instance from another class can talk to it.

Comment: so how can I declare this instance?

Comment: Class1 *myFirstObject = [[Class1 alloc] init];

Comment: But seriously, if you have to ask this please pick up a good book that introduces you to Object Oriented programming for iOS, you will thank me for it soon. Take care.